# How do I copy varying filenames into Vagrant box (in a platform independent way)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, vagrant-aws

I'm trying to use Vagrant to deploy to AWS using the [vagrant-aws](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) plugin.

This means I need a box, then I need to add a versioned jar (je.g. `myApp-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar`) and some statically named files.  This also need to be able to work on Windows or Linux machines.

I can use config.vm.synced_folder locally with a setup.sh to move the files I need using wildcards (e.g. `cp myApp-*.jar`) but the plugin only supports [rsync](/questions/tagged/rsync), so only Linux.

**TLDR**; Is there a way to copy files using wildcards in Vagrant

Answer (score 1):

> This means I need a box

Yes and No. vagrant heavily relies on the box concept but in the context of AWS provider, the box is a dummy box. the system will look at the `aws.*` variable to connect to your account.

vagrant will spin an ec2 instance and will connect to it, you need to make sure the instance will be linked with a security group that allows the connection and open the port to your IP (at minimum)

if you are running a provisioner, please note the script is run from the ec2 instance not from your local.

what I suggest is the following: 
- copy the jar files that are necessary on s3 or somewhere the ec2 instance can easily access them
- run the provisioner to fetch the files from this source (s3) 
- let it go.

If you have quick turnaround of files in development mode, you can push to a git repo that the ec2 instance can pull the files and deploy the jar directly

Comment: The problem is that these "files" contain my binary.  My app is a jar and I want to automate the process in the build pipeline so that a commit, leads to a build which leads to an up to date AWS deploy.  I can do what you suggest with config perhaps but the jar is only created at the end of the build and it would be a manual step to copy the jar to S3 then a rebuild of EC2.

Comment: Ok i am not sure of all your details of your build but could you generate the jar artifact and push it to the ec2 instance

Comment: Not in a platform independent way I don't think